# How to access GCP vertex AI using python code without installing Google cloud sdk?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, artificial-intelligence, google-cloud-vertex-ai

Using GCP vertex AI, I developed an application that can perform NLP-related tasks. The issue now is that I have to test it on a new PC without the Google Cloud SDK installed. I need to log in and access vertex AI API's using credentials.json.

I have all the details which can be required to log into GCP. For instance (credentials.json, project_name, project_id, region) etc.

How to access the vertex AI APIs without installing the Google cloud SDK? Similar to how we use to access hugging face or OpenAI models and their API's by using tokens to log in .

Comment: I have the same issue! Did you find a solution for this? If so, please share!